# How to print via wifi from Windows mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

Could I print the wifi on a windows mobile in c# without connecting or downloading the application on a mobile? Is there a way to print wifi using just the emulator?

Comment: Diana can you tell us more and in a bit clearer way? Do you want to print via wifi from your windows mobile application? Which version of Windows Mobile and Compact Framework or Windows Phone 7 and Silverlight?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2008 , windows mobile 6.0. I have a simple example of how to detect wifi from a mobile device. When I run the application, there is no wifi detection in the mobile emulator. I guess the problem is the fact that I did not connect a windows mobile phone. How can I solve the problem? I do not have a mobile so I would like to use the emulator. Should I install a virtual machine?Thx

Answer (score 0):

No. Windows mobile does not have printer drivers, so it can't connect to a printer the way your PC can.

You do have other options, though:

1. You can upload your document to a cloud service like Google Docs then use their [print capability](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/p/cloudprint.html).
2. You can upload the document to your PC and print from there.

-PaulH

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google Cloud Print you can then send a print job like in [this example](http://pastie.org/1733781)